Unique indexes are not necessarily in the table_constraints view: so how to find them using the information_schema?
This query will not find unique indexes not explicitly used in conjunction with a constraint:
select TC.Constraint_Name, CC.Column_Name 
from information_schema.table_constraints TC
inner join information_schema.constraint_column_usage CC
on TC.Constraint_Name = CC.Constraint_Name
where TC.constraint_type = 'Unique'
order by TC.Constraint_Name

So then how can an implied unique constraint such as the following be found using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA ?
create unique constraint PipelineSummary_CorrelationId on
bronze.AggregatedPipelineSummary (CorrelationId);


Why the close vote?

Its not, its a transfer to a better site i.e. https://dba.stackexchange.com/

that's interesting: so SQL is not a solid SOF topic anymore? This is for SQL development not for DBA work.

I would avoid the information_schema stuff, it's mostly from compatibility. Check out sys.indexes and sys.objects instead

@WestCoastProjects it's just about getting your question in front of the best experts. So when it's getting into more technical database questions, beyond dev and queries, you'te more likely to get a better/faster answer there.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views provide a standardized and simplified view of your database catalog.  It's limited to displaying the "logical" view of your database, and won't display many of the SQL Server-specific aspects of your database design.
So use SQL Server's native catalog views instead, here sys.indexes, eg:
select o.name table_name, i.name index_name, i.is_unique_constraint
from sys.objects o
join sys.indexes i
  on o.object_id = i.object_id
where is_unique=1
and o.is_ms_shipped = 0


OK I had set up some elaborate queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA but will basically start over - given an official-ish response here. Thanks for your input!
